# How give the user options to download or open in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found some content about opening PDF in a new tab and others to automatically download it.

But it's a lot of manual stuff I have here, so I think it's better to the COMMON user choose that way. I know he can open in new tab and save it from there. But this can be a slow approach.

So is this:

1) The user will click the link

2) A kind of Confirm box will show

3) He will choose: download or open it in new browser/window.

Comment: Can't be forced. Some browsers have a built-in viewer, or will automatically launch an external viewer, regardless of the MIME-type.

Comment: I understood. For example, when I click in a PDF document, my Firefox ask me what I want do to. But my Chrome just open in a new tab. An option maybe is having an link with zip file, so he will certainly download it, and the pdf link God will choose it?

Answer (score 1):

Though you should normally leave decision like this to the client and his browser, you can probably make the client download the file if you serve it as `application/octet-stream` using the HTTP `Content-type` header.